# No Styling for the datepicker in Wordpress admin

Tags: jquery-ui, plugins

I'm developing a plugin for Wordpress and I need a datepicker. So I enqueue the jquery and jquery-ui

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
```

and called the datepicker

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#date').datepicker({});
});
```

It worked pretty well, however my datepicker has no style at all. Anyone knows how to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Here ya go ... try this:

```
        /* add jquery ui datepicker and theme */
        global $wp_scripts;
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
        $ui = $wp_scripts->query('jquery-ui-core');
        $url = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/{$ui->ver}/themes/redmond/jquery.ui.all.css";
        wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-redmond', $url, false, $ui->ver);
```

This is what I use in my plugin to load a theme.  That CDN has all the basic jquery-ui themes.

Hope this helps ...